# Remove ASCII signs - problem with regexmatch function in AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, regular-expressions, email-studio

I'm trying to remove from the beginning and end of the word the \x00-\x20 signs. I don't know what is not working when I'm applying the code I'm not receiving any result. Any thoughts?

`SET @regex = regexmatch(@OrderID, '^[[:alpha:]]+/$’ , 0, 'IgnoreCase', 'Multiline')`

This one is only working on the RexEx checker but not in Marketing Cloud

`SET @regex = regexmatch(@OrderID, '[\x00-\x20]' , 0, 'IgnoreCase', 'Multiline')`

Not working at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to strip any non-numeric characters, you can do something like this in your AMPscript block:

```
%%[

var @OrderID, @i, @char, @OrderIDNum
set @OrderID = "*12345!"

for @i = 1 to length(@OrderID) do

  set @char = substring(@OrderID, @i, 1)

  if not empty(regexmatch(@char, '[0-9]', 0, "IgnoreCase", "Multiline")) then
    set @OrderIDNum = concat(@OrderIDNum, @char)
  endif

next @i

output(concat("<br>OrderID: ", @OrderID))
output(concat("<br>OrderIDNum: ", @OrderIDNum))

]%%
```

**Output:**

```
*12345!
12345
```

**Reference:**

- [regexmatch](https://ampscript.guide/regexmatch/)
- [Jake314159](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/250038/5202)